Maximal bijection-dodging families on $\mathbb{N}$
We say that a family ${\cal S}\subseteq{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ is bijection-dodging if  there is a bijection $\varphi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with $\varphi(T)\notin {\cal S}$ for all $T\in{\cal S}$.
Given a bijection-dodging family ${\cal S}\subseteq{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$, is there necessarily a bijection-dodging ${\cal S}_0\subseteq{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ with ${\cal S}\subseteq{\cal S}_0$, and for every $X\in{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})\setminus{\cal S}_0$ we have that ${\cal S}_0\cup\{X\}$ is no longer bijection-dodging?
(Of course, one reflex is to use Zorn's Lemma, but there is a chain of bijection-dodging families with their union no longer being bijection-dodging.)

I dont understand the last sentence. If the union of a chain $S_i$ is no longer bijection dodging, then we can find a $T\in \bigcup_i S_i$ with $\varphi(T)\in \bigcup_i S_i$, e.g. we can find $j,k$ such that $T\in S_j$ and $\varphi(T)\in S_k$. Using the chain condition, we can pick the maximum of $j,k$ and thus assume that $j=k$, e.g. already $S_j$ cannot be bijection dodging.

@HenrikRüping: Each $S_i$ has its own $\varphi_i$.

Seeing ${\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ as ${0,1}^\omega$ in the alternative notation of binary $\omega$-languages, here is an example of a singleton-saturated bijection-dodging family ${\cal S}_0$, maybe the simplest and too $\omega$-regular: ${00, 11}^*01{0,1}^\omega$.
-- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_language

Not that it would include many bijection-dodging families ${\cal S}$, unfortunately.

@ClaudeChaunier Do your considerations lead to a proof that every bijection-dodging family is contained in a maximal such one?

Do you know the answer for $\mathcal S=\varnothing$, i.e., do you know if there is any maximal bijection-dodging family?

Do you know the answer to the analogous question about families $\mathcal S\subseteq[\mathbb N]^{\lt\omega}$ or $\mathcal S\subseteq[\mathbb N]^2$ instead of $\mathcal S\subseteq\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$?

@bof, ${\cal S}_0 := {00, 11}^*01{0,1}^\omega$ is such a maximal bijection-dodging family, where I use binary words to show the value of the indicator function ${\mathbf 1}_X$ for the sets $X\in{\cal S}_0$ on $0, 1, 2, \dots$. The associated bijection is the permutation $\varphi_0 := (1;0)(3;2)\dots(2k+1;;k)\dots;$ swapping odd numbers with their even predecessor. It is maximal because ${\cal P}({\mathbb N})\setminus{\cal S}_0 = {00, 11}^*10{0,1}^\omega = \varphi_0({\cal S}_0)$ and $\varphi_0(\varphi_0({\cal S}_0)) = {\cal S}_0$.

In other words, ${00, 11}^*01{0,1}^\omega$ is ${X \subseteq {\mathbb N}$ such that there is some $n$ with $2n\notin X$ and $2n+1\in X$ and no $k\in{0,1,\dots,n-1}$ with $2k\in X$ and $2k+1\notin X$ $}$.

When allowing only finite subsets of $\mathbb N$, there is ${\cal S}_0 := {00, 11}^01{0,1}^$ as an example of a maximal bijection-dodging family. And there always is some max when starting from any bijection-dodging family $\mathcal S\subseteq[\mathbb N]^{\lt\omega}$. Enumerate all $X\in[\mathbb N]^{\lt\omega}\setminus{\mathcal S}$. If you find some with ${\cal S}\cup{X}$ still bijection-dodging, then add $X$ to $S$ and start over. If you don't find any such $X$ any more, you are done. This is classically well-defined because the loops are countable.

@ClaudeChaunier I must be misunderstanding something, but it seems to me that if $X={0011}^\omega$ then $X\notin\mathcal S$ and $\mathbb N\setminus X\notin\mathcal S$.

@ClaudeChaunier My bad, I typed $=$ when I meant $\neq$. Bijection-dodging: there is a bijection $\varphi$ such that $\mathcal S\cap\varphi(\mathcal S)=\varnothing$. Not bijection-dodging: for every bijection $\varphi$ we have $\mathcal S\cap\varphi(\mathcal S)\neq\varnothing$.

@bof, you are right, about $X=(0011)^\omega$ too, thanks. I got my justification wrong and ${\mathcal P}({\mathbb N}) = ({00, 11}^*01{0,1}^\omega)\sqcup({00, 11}^*10{0,1}^\omega)\sqcup({00,11}^\omega)$. Truly, ${\cal S}_0 = {00, 11}^*01{0,1}^\omega$ is maximal because suppose there is a bijection $\varphi$ with $({\cal S}_0\cup{X})\cap\varphi({\cal S}_0\cup{X})=\varnothing$. Then $\varphi(1)=0$ and $\varphi(0)=1$ otherwise there would be room enough to send some $Y\in 01{0,1}^\omega\subseteq{\cal S}_0$ into ${\cal S}_0$ with some elementary juggling...

... Then as well $\varphi(3)=2$ and $\varphi(2)=3$ and so on and $\varphi = \varphi_0 = (1;0)(3;2)\dots(2k+1;;k)\dots;$. Now if you took $X\in{00,11}^\omega$ you would get $\varphi(X)=X$, a contradiction. Or you took $X\in{00, 11}^*10{0,1}^\omega$ and you would get $\varphi(X)\in{\cal S}_0$ a contradiction too.
